# Tkinter Label with set and get method PAY_VAR() error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm self thought using books, ebooks and yotube tutorials. I'm currently reading Tkinter GUI Programming by Example by David Love. I encounter error while re writing the code in his book (page18).

So here's the code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Hello Tkinter")

        self.label_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Choose One")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=100, pady=30)

        hello_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Hello", command=self.say_hello)
        hello_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20,0), pady=(0,20))

        goodbye_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Goodbye",
                                command=self.say_goodbye)
        goodbye_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=(0,20), pady=(0,20))

    def say_hello(self):
        self.label_text.set(text="Hello World")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        self.label_text.set(text="Goodbye! \n (Closing in 2 seconds)")
        self.after(2000, self.destroy)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        window = Window()
        window.mainloop()
```

After building the code, the label should show "Choose One", but it is not. It showed `PY_VAR()`
[image: After building the code, the label should show "Choose One", but it is not. It showed "PY_VAR().]

I literally copied his code, why it's not working. Could you help me?
I want to understand what's wrong with the code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `text=self.label_text` --> `textvariable=self.label_text`

Comment: I'm getting a new error..

Comment: hello.py", line 23, in say_hello
    self.label_text.set(text="Hello World")
TypeError: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: line 26, in say_goodbye
    self.label_text.set(text="Goodbye! \n (Closing in 2 seconds)")

Comment: because that method has no argument `text`, either use `value="string here"` or just `"string here"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `text` and `textvariable`. `text` is the face value of the word which is displayed on the GUI. What you probably mean is

```
self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.label_text)
```

Addressing the second issue, you directly have to pass the string which it should set as its value

```
def say_hello(self):
        self.label_text.set("Hello World")

def say_goodbye(self):
        self.label_text.set("Goodbye! \n (Closing in 2 seconds)")
        self.after(2000, self.destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of errors regarding `StringVar` set using `text=`.

The code now works

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Hello Tkinter")

        self.label_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Choose One")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.label_text)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=100, pady=30)

        hello_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Hello", command=self.say_hello)
        hello_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20,0), pady=(0,20))

        goodbye_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Goodbye",
                                command=self.say_goodbye)
        goodbye_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=(0,20), pady=(0,20))

    def say_hello(self):
        self.label_text.set("Hello World")

    def say_goodbye(self):
        self.label_text.set("Goodbye! \n (Closing in 2 seconds)")
        self.after(2000, self.destroy)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: how to correct this code? I'm sorry, I'm literally lost here. Can you show me a line of code to correct David's code?

Comment: Look at the `self.label` declaration and notice the use of `textvariable` instead of `text`. Also functions say_hello and say_goodbye have the same problems, that is they include the word `text=` in the `self.label_text.set` statement. Those were your problems.

Comment: @Derek Why are you using a `textvariable` instead of just using `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=...)`?

Comment: I'm setting the textvariable to a `StringVar` not displaying a text message. That was the original OP's error.

Comment: thanks alot! I'm also at fault too... I've written a wrong code from his book... in def say_hello... should not have text="...." there.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good one  @ColBeans.Python. Happy coding.

Comment: @Derek Even if it's OP's original error, I think you should add a note to your answer saying that it will be easier (and faster) to just use `.config`